# ソフトウェアライセンスに関する質問をどう考えるか

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

[Rubyのバイナリを作成したソフトにバンドルして配布しても良いでしょうか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/2816/30)

は、ソフトウェアライセンスに関する質問です。プログラミング技術に直接関わる質問ではなく、どう扱うか意見が分かれるトピックだと思います。

- [英語版SOではオフトピック](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/20226)
- [Programmers.SEではソフトウェアライセンスに関する一般的な質問はオントピック](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7051/18425)だが、個別の法律相談に類するような質問はオフトピック

日本語版SOではどう扱うのがよいでしょうか。オフトピックとするか、オントピックとするか、特定の種類に限定するかなど。

Answer (score 10):

私見では:

「プログラマーの仕事に役立つ回答を提供できるか」という点に立ち返って考えると、

- ソフトウェアライセンスに関わる問題は、プログラマーが仕事上ぶつかる可能性のある問題である
- ソフトウェアライセンスについて、プログラマー (このサイトのユーザー) が実経験に基づいた知識を持っていることが期待できる
- 個別の事例で裁判になった時の責任は取れない

ということから、「個別の事例でどうすべきか」という質問で**なければ**、ソフトウェアライセンスそのものに関する質問はオントピックでよいのではないかと思います。

「裁判になった時の責任は取れない」は[利用規約](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service) (英語) に明記されてはいますが、個別の事例でどうすべきかは権威のある回答を提供できない以上、ここでは生産的なQ&Aにならないと考えます。

(基本的にProgrammers.SEと同じ立場の意見です。)

この考え方に基づいたオントピックな質問の例

- GPLなコードをサーバサイドで使っていいのか (GPLの解釈に関する質問)
- Rubyのバイナリを作成したソフトにバンドルして配布しても良いか (Rubyのライセンスの解釈に関する質問)

どれも個別の事例に関する質問とボーダーラインとも言えるので、「専門家にご相談ください」の注意書きを回答に付けた方が誤解がないと思います。

オフトピックな質問の例

- 委託契約で書いたコードを個人的に再利用してもいいのでしょうか (個々の事例に依存する)

Comment: 私も「ソフトウェアライセンスそのものに関する質問はオントピックでよい」と思います。

Answer (score 3):

「一般に知られるソフトウェアライセンスそのもの」についての質問はオントピックで良いと思います。解釈が曖昧な部分で、「〜してよいか」「〜してはだめか」の判断をあおぐような質問が問題だと思います。英語版では、そのような質問はオフトピックになりがちながら、ボーダーが曖昧という印象を受けています。

先ほど、[ライセンスについての質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/3040/mit%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E3%82%92%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E8%A1%A8%E8%A8%98?noredirect=1#comment1578_3040)がふたたびありましたので、必要なタグを二つ作成しました。

- `licensing` : ライセンスを行うソフトウェアへの質問用タグ

  > このタグはライセンスを提供するソフトウェアについての質問に付けるようにしてください。（例：ライセンス提供サーバとそのクライアント）また、このタグを使い、法的な助言を求めることをしないでください。
- `mit-license` : MIT License そのものについての質問用タグ

  > MIT License (エムアイティー・ライセンス)は、マサチューセッツ工科大学(MIT)を起源とするフリーソフトウェアライセンスです。これは Permissive なライセンスと呼ばれ、ライセンス文が共に配布されるかぎりプロプライエタリなソフトウェアでも利用可能であるという、制限のゆるいものです。GPLとの互換性があります。

少しセンシティブかなと思いましたので、タグの説明は英語版をできるだけそのまま訳しています。英語版では、ライセンスそのものを扱う質問に対し `license` タグや `licensing` タグの使用を好ましくないとしていました。

Comment: 英語版SOで`licensing`が「ライセンスを提供するソフトウェア」限定なのは、[ライセンスそのものに関する質問がオフトピック](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/20226)だからですね。Programmers.SEではオントピックなので、[そちらの`licensing`タグ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/licensing/info)は「ライセンスの適用の仕方」という感じの利用案内になっています。日本語版ではライセンスそのものに関する質問を受ける方向でよさそうなので、Programmersのタグ付けの仕方を流用してもいいと思います。