# 法律についての質問をどう扱うか

Tags: 討議, 話題の範囲

プログラミングをしていると、時折日本や海外の法律との関連が気になることがあります。たとえば、以下のような場合です。

- 技適に通っていない Raspberry Pi を日本で起動してプログラミングできますか？
- Cookie使用を確認するサイトが増えたのはなぜ？ ([類似する参考質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44756/19110))
- 電波法に触れないように Wi-Fi を設定するには？ ([類似する参考質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/45208/19110))

このような質問は、どう処理すれば良いのでしょうか？　というのも、以下の不安があるからです。

- 私も含め多くのユーザーは法律の専門家ではなく、正確な回答が正当に評価されているのか分からない。
- 回答に間違いが含まれていたとき発生する影響が相対的に大きそう。特に、責任問題に発展した際どうなるのか分からない。
- 本家 Stack Overflow では法律に関する質問は[オフトピックとされている](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280151/5989200)。

また、関連する[過去のメタ議論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1541/19110)として、ソフトウェアライセンスについての質問は ja.SO では限定的にオントピックとされています。

では、ライセンス以外の問題については、どう扱うべきでしょうか？　トピックに沿っているかどうか、オントピックなら種類を限定すべきかどうか、を考えたいです。

Comment: これが参考になると思ってます。 https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1655/205420

Comment: @YukiInoue なるほど、雑に訳すと SoftwareEngineering.SE では「SE ネットワークでも答えられる法律系質問はあるものの、常識が求められるよね」「法律系質問に対する常識的な回答は常に "弁護士に聞け" であるが、だからといって質問が成立しない訳ではない。"私の場合はこのように解決した" という、経験に基づく回答はありえる」「このため、専門家が一般的な回答をできそうな質問はオントピックにでき、個人的な法律相談はオフトピックである」といった[投稿](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1660/257670)があったのですね。とはいえ別の方が「ダメだ。たとえば "私は法律家で無いので詳しくないが〜" といった形の投稿は回答ではない。最悪、一見正しそうだが間違っている内容かもしれない」という[投稿](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1671/257670)もなさっていて、議論が終結していない印象も受けます。

Comment: 後者の「電波法～」は＋票もあり比較的受け入れられているような感じですが、クローズ票も現時点で２票ありますね。実際法律が絡むことを想定していなかった質問のようなので今回の議題とは微妙な感じです。インフラ関係の質問のようにも捉えられるので私としては問題ないようにも思えるのですが、どうなんでしょうね？究極、私はコミュニティに受け入れられていればOKなのかなぁですが…

Answer (score 5):

個人的には「**適法か否か**」を問うような質問は法律の話がメインになるのでオフトピック、そうでなければ（回答できる人がいれば）アドバイスしてあげる分には問題無いのではと思います。

無線LANの質問ははじめから「電波法に触れないように使うには」という様な聞き方では無かった気がします。クローズ票は「プログラムに関する質問ではないから」が理由ではないでしょうか。

Comment: 書き方が悪かったのですが、リンクした質問はあくまで関連する参考質問のつもりでした。

Answer (score 3):

ここはプログラミングについての質問サイトなので、プログラミングに限定するべきだと思います。
　法律の質問が混じると、どこまでプログラミングの質問と法律の質問が入り混じるか検討がつきません。
　法律は客観的に解釈しようという理想はあるものの、現実的には主観的な部分が多くウェートを占めています。解釈をめぐっては学説が分かれており、常に一義的に定まるものではありません。
　社会の変化によって、変わることがあります。
　違反すると、責任問題に発展することがあります。現実的行動を通して何かが起きた「後から」やって来るという性質があります。
　詳しい人が少ないため、チェックが働きにくいという悩みがあります。

これに対して、プログラミングは、その名前の通り事前計画です。エディタとコンパイラがあれば、手前で動作確認を行うことが出来、何か誤りがあればコードの書き換えによって修正を行うことが出来ます。間違えは実証的であり、間違いは間違いであると示してくれます。コードの表現やスピードの違いはあれど、動作は一義的であって、現実的に製品マスターとなり社会の構成に組み込んだり、顧客から金をとるまでの準備段階では、責任の発生はないに等しいです。
　
　されど、私たちはプログラマとして常に法律上の制約を受けていると言えます。
そして法律とは、我々が達成する最小限度のルールであると言えます。とすれば、常に我々と関係しているうえ、最小限度のルールであるならば、その知識はむしろ日常的となるべきであり、常識化するべきであるともいえます。
　
　上の法律の問題点をクリアした上でなら、例外的に認めてもいい場合があると考えます。

・ソフトウェアの開発に関係する法律の範囲を限定すること。
　・ユーザーの実体験に基づいた解答であること。

１．ソフトウェアの開発に関係する法律の範囲を限定することは言うまでもありません。
おそらく、いちいち言わなくてもそうなるかと思います。
　２．大切なのはこの部分で、誰かが地雷を踏んでおいてくれるのがありがたいです。
そのときの具体的な事実を列挙し、そのような場合、法律上の問題にはならなかった。
という実体験に基づくものであれば、そこに嘘が入り込む余地はなく、周りの評価が入り込む余地もありません。プログラムのように、事前に実証することが出来ないため、人柱が重要となってしまいます。
　
　３-1．これは上の話とは別で、モデレーターの判断により、法律の質問が来た場合にその都度判断する。という事があります。モデレーターも法律の専門家ではないですが、リンクに挙げられたような質問であれば、総合考慮して、プログラマにとってプラスになる質問であると判断すれば、そのまま残しておいてもよく、そうでないとすれば、自治機能によってオフトピックにするという考えも出来ます。（ただそこが質問の原点なのでしょうけれども・・・。）いわば、法律の問題は、具体的なプログラマの動きがあってこそ、つみあげられていくものでもあり、そんな問題があったのか。と初めて分かる場合があります。事前に役に立つ、立たないということを峻別することはできません。電波法の問題も、そのような質問あってくれたおかげで、問題意識を持つことが出来た。という意味で、非常に役に立つのではないか。と私個人は思います。その点はプログラミングと似ている面があります。
　一言でいえば、モデレーターを含む、自治機能に任せればどうか。という事でもあります。
　
　3-2．上記に述べたように、法律はやっかい極まりないです。回答は正しくなくてもいいけど、こんな法律上の疑問があるんだ。という疑問投げ入れ堂みたいなものでもない限り、扱えないものはすっぱりと切った方がいいのではないか。と考えます。
　
　3-3．はっきりしない。泳がせておくというのも一手です。あくまでもここは
個人的な見解のある質問サイトであり、こういうところで質問をした人が悪いのです。その解答を信じて行動をして何か問題が起きてもその人が悪いのですから、放っておくのがいいのかもしれません。
　
　
　脳内会議結果　オフトピック：3票　オントピック:1票  どちらでもない:1票